# Collision detection for circles

Tags: java, awt, collision-detection

I have a simple Java applet that has two user-controlled balls, drawn using `java.awt`. I need a way to detect a collision with between them. I have an algorithm for detecting collision with the walls:

```
if (xPosition > (300 - radius)){
   xSpeed = -xSpeed; 
}
else if (xPosition < radius){
   xSpeed = -xSpeed; 
}
else if (yPosition > (300 - radius)) {
   ySpeed = -ySpeed;
}
else if (yPosition < radius){
   ySpeed = -ySpeed;
}
xPosition += xSpeed;
yPosition += ySpeed;
```

and for the second ball:

```
if (xPosition2 > (300 - radius)){
   xSpeed2 = -xSpeed2; 
}
else if (xPosition2 < radius){
   xSpeed2 = -xSpeed2; 
}
else if (yPosition2 > (300 - radius)) {
   ySpeed2 = -ySpeed2;
}
else if (yPosition2 < radius){
   ySpeed2 = -ySpeed2;
}
xPosition2 += xSpeed2;
yPosition2 += ySpeed2;
```

- The applet is 300 pixels by 300 pixels.
- `radius` stores the radius of the circles.
- `xPosition` and `xPosition2` store the x coordinates for the two balls.
- `yPosition` and `yPosition` store the y coordinates for the two balls,
- `xSpeed` and `xSpeed2` store the x velocities for the two balls.
- `ySpeed` and `ySpeed2` store the y velocities for the two balls.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Bob.  This is really more of a math question than a programming question, since there's no way to do what you want built into the Java language.  To get you started, though, think of it this way: detecting collisions means detecting when the balls will overlap or touch, right?  And you know their positions and sizes....

Comment: Ya, but I can't think of anything. I tried doing it through math and I ended up with balls passing through each other and about 30 lines of useless code

Answer (score 6):

Use http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.html, there's a distance method there, if it's less than the radius they're colliding.

EDIT:
Err, less than the radius * 2 , sorry

Comment: Kool thanks! I had heard of an intersecting command.. but apparently that only works with rectangles.

Comment: In memory of Bob Twinkles, I had +1

Comment: I just looked at it, but how do you pass the positions to the method

Comment: You'll have ti instantiate the Point2d. I would recomend you to store the position using this class.

Comment: int startingXPosition =0;
  int startingYPosition =0;
  java.awt.Point position = new java.awt.Point(startingXPosition,startingYPosition);

declare point as a field and use position.getX() and position.getY().

The collision teste:

boolean isColliding = position.distance(anotherBall.getPosition()) < radius + anotherBall.getRadius;

Answer (score 1):

There's Point2D in Java or you can do it yourself, it is trivially easy for circle/circle collisions or sphere/sphere collisions.

```
int distXX = (xPosition1 - xPosition2) * (xPosition1 - xPosition2);
int distYY = (yPosition1 - yPosition2) * (yPosition1 - yPosition2);
if ( radius*radius > distXX * distYY ) {
   ...  // There's a collision
}
```

Comment: Note that the typical game developer newbie error would be to start using "square roots" to compute distance and check with the radius, instead of not square-rooting and checking with the *radius x radius*.   The solution above is using only discrete match and actually *is* what is used in a *lot* of games (been writing games decades ago, this was *the* way to do it).

Comment: ok I just compiled and ran and the ball colided with everyhing but the other ball

Answer (score 0):

```
 public boolean colliding(Ball anotherBall) {
    double xDelta = (this.x + this.ballSize/2 + this.dx) - (anotherBall.x + anotherBall.ballSize/2 + anotherBall.dx);
    double YDelta = (this.y + this.ballSize/2 + this.dy) - (anotherBall.y + anotherBall.ballSize/2 + anotherBall.dy);
    double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xDelta, 2) + Math.pow(YDelta, 2));

    return (distance <= this.ballSize/2 + anotherBall.ballSize/2);

}
```

Comment: erm that's nice but I'm running the entire app of one class

Answer (score -1):

This Link is pretty useful!

[Circle-Circle Collisions](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/when-worlds-collide-simulating-circle-circle-collisions--gamedev-769)

It's very detailed and didatic

---

At the bottom of that page there are another links, to even more detailed stuff!

---

I used the Distance Between Centers method  ---
[Circles](https://cdn.tutsplus.com/active/uploads/legacy/tuts/393_qtCollisionDetection123/assets/circles_distance.png)

By measuring the distance between each center you can say if they are colliding.
The distance should never be more then the sum of the 2 radius.

Here's what I did:

```
private boolean checkDrawContains(ShapeDrawable newHole) 
{
    long newCenterX = newHole.getBounds().left + (newHole.getBounds().width()/2); //Get the center of my shapes
    long newCenterY = newHole.getBounds().top + (newHole.getBounds().height()/2);

    for(ShapeDrawable hole: mHoles) // I was storing the circles in an ArrayList
    { 
        long centerX = hole.getBounds().left + (hole.getBounds().width()/2); //Get the center of my shapes
        long centerY = hole.getBounds().top + (hole.getBounds().height()/2);
        long x = centerX - newCenterX;
        long y = centerY - newCenterY;
        long aux = (long) ((Math.pow(Math.abs(x),2)) + (Math.pow(Math.abs(y),2))); //Pythagoras the hard way :P
        long distance = (long) Math.sqrt(aux);
        long sRads = (newHole.getBounds().width()/2) + (hole.getBounds().width()/2);

        if(distance <=  sRads ) {
            return true;  //Is Colliding!
        }
    }
    return false; // Is not Colliding!
}
```