# How to make the ball bounce off the circle Graphic2D? - Java

Tags: java

I'm working on Air Hockey game. Until now, I've moved both handles and bounce the ball in my Air Hockey table actually ball can bounce off the walls, but my problem is I can't hit the ball with my handles and I don't have any idea for that. I searched in the net but I couldn't find any thing. I'll appreciate if you help me as soon as you can!!

This is all my code that you need:

```
public class StartGamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener, Runnable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
double xCircle1=200;
double yCircle1 =100 ;

double xCircle2=200;
double yCircle2 =700 ;

 double xBall=200;
 double yBall=400;
 double rBall=20;

 double ballSpeedX=-3;
 double ballSpeedY=0;

 private Ball m_ball = new Ball(0, 0, 7, 7);

 private int   m_interval  = 35; 
 private Timer m_timer;           

double dx = 0, dy = 0, dx2=0, dy2=0;
private Graphics2D circle1;
private Graphics2D circle2;
private Graphics2D circle3;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f=new JFrame();
        f.setSize(new Dimension(512,837));
        StartGamePanel p=new StartGamePanel();
        f.add(p);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

public StartGamePanel(){
    m_timer = new Timer(m_interval, new TimerAction());
    m_timer.start();  // start animation by starting the timer.
      Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
        t.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
}


 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

          addKeyListener(this);

          ContainerTable table=new ContainerTable(2, 0, 493, 800, new Color(51,153,255), Color.WHITE);
          table.draw(g);

        circle1 = (Graphics2D) g;
       circle1.setColor(new Color(255,51,51));
       Shape theCircle = new Ellipse2D.Double(xCircle1 - 40, yCircle1 - 40, 2.0 * 40, 2.0 * 40);
       circle1.fill(theCircle);


         circle2 = (Graphics2D) g;
           circle2.setColor(new Color(255,102,102));
            Shape theCircle2 = new Ellipse2D.Double(xCircle1 - 35, yCircle1 - 35, 2.0 * 35, 2.0 * 35);
            circle2.fill(theCircle2);

             circle3 = (Graphics2D) g;
               circle3.setColor(new Color(255,51,51));
                Shape theCircle3 = new Ellipse2D.Double(xCircle1 - 20, yCircle1 - 20, 2.0 * 20, 2.0 * 20);
                circle3.fill(theCircle3);

       Graphics2D circleprim = (Graphics2D) g;
       circleprim.setColor(new Color(0,51,102));
      Shape theCircleprim = new Ellipse2D.Double(xCircle2 - 40, yCircle2 - 40, 2.0 * 40, 2.0 * 40);
      circleprim.fill(theCircleprim);

     Graphics2D circle2prim = (Graphics2D) g;
       circle2prim.setColor(new Color(0,102,204));
       Shape theCircle2prim = new Ellipse2D.Double(xCircle2 - 35, yCircle2 - 35, 2.0 * 35, 2.0 * 35);
       circle2prim.fill(theCircle2prim);

      Graphics2D  circle3prim = (Graphics2D) g;
       circle3prim.setColor(new Color(0,51,102));
       Shape theCircle3prim = new Ellipse2D.Double(xCircle2 - 20, yCircle2 - 20, 2.0 * 20, 2.0 * 20);
     circle3prim.fill(theCircle3prim);

    g.setColor(Color.gray);
     m_ball.draw(g);

      Graphics2D goal = (Graphics2D) g;
       goal.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      goal.fill3DRect(100, 0, 300, 10, true);

      Graphics2D goal2 = (Graphics2D) g;
       goal2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      goal2.fill3DRect(100, 790, 300, 10, true);




    }

 class TimerAction implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            m_ball.setBounds(getWidth(), getHeight());
            m_ball.move();  
            repaint();      
        }
    }

     @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
        xCircle1 += dx;
        yCircle1 += dy;
        yCircle2 += dy2;
        xCircle2+= dx2;

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            if(yCircle1>40){
                dy = -2;
                dx = 0;
            }else{
                yCircle1=40;
                dy *= -1;
                dx=0;
            }

        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            if(yCircle1<360){

                dy = 2;
                dx = 0;
                }else{
                    yCircle1=360;
                    dx =0;
                    dy *= -1;
                }
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            if (xCircle1 < 30) {
                xCircle1=30;
                dy = 0;
                dx *= -1;
            }else {
            dy = 0;
            dx = -2;
            }
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            if (xCircle1 > 460) {
                xCircle1= 460;

                dx *= -1;
                dy = 0;
            }else{
                dy = 0;
                dx = 2;
            }

        }

        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_F) {
            if (xCircle2 > 460) {
                xCircle2= 460;
                dy2 = 0;
                dx2 *= -1;
            }else{
            dy2 = 0;
            dx2 = 2;
        }
        }

        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            if (xCircle2 < 30) {
                xCircle2=30; 
                dy2 = 0;
                dx2 *= -1;
            }else {
            dy2 = 0;
            dx2 = -2;
            }
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_E) {
            if(yCircle2>430){

            dy2 = -2;
            dx2 = 0;
        }else{
            yCircle2=430;
            dy*= -1;
            dx=0;
        }}
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_D) {

            if(yCircle2>750){
                yCircle2=750;
                dy2 *= -1;
                dx2=0;
            }else{
            dy2 = 2;
            dx2 = 0;
        }}
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            dy = 0;
            dx = 0;
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
            dy = 0;
            dx = 0;
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            dy = 0;
            dx = 0;
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            dy = 0;
            dx = 0;
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_E) {
            dy2 = 0;
            dx2 = 0;
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            dy2 = 0;
            dx2 = 0;
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            dy2 = 0;
            dx2 = 0;
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_F) {
            dy2 = 0;
            dx2 = 0;
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY); 
        while (true) 
        { 
          xBall += ballSpeedX;
          yBall += ballSpeedX;

          repaint();

          if (xBall  < 30) {
              ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX; 
            xBall = 30; 
          } 

          if (xBall  > 470) {
              ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX; 
            xBall = 470; 
          } 


          try { Thread.sleep (20); } 



          catch (InterruptedException ex) {} 

        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY); }}}




    class Ball {

final static int DIAMETER = 50;

private int m_x;          
private int m_y;

private int m_velocityX;   
private int m_velocityY;

private int m_rightBound;  
private int m_bottomBound;


public Ball(int x, int y, int velocityX, int velocityY) {
m_x = x;
m_y = y;
m_velocityX = velocityX;
m_velocityY = velocityY;
}

public void setBounds(int width, int height) {
m_rightBound  = width  - DIAMETER;
m_bottomBound = height - DIAMETER;
}

public void move() {
m_x += m_velocityX;
m_y += m_velocityY;        

if (m_x < 0) {                 
m_x         = 0;           
m_velocityX = -m_velocityX; 

} else if (m_x > m_rightBound) { 
m_x         = m_rightBound;    
m_velocityX = -m_velocityX; 
}

if (m_y < 0) {                 
m_y       = 0;
m_velocityY = -m_velocityY;

} else if (m_y > m_bottomBound) {
m_y       =  m_bottomBound;
m_velocityY = -m_velocityY;
}
}

public void draw(Graphics g) {
g.fillOval(m_x, m_y, DIAMETER, DIAMETER);
}

public int  getDiameter() { return DIAMETER;}
public int  getX()        { return m_x;}
public int  getY()        { return m_y;}

public void setPosition(int x, int y) {
m_x = x;
m_y = y;
}
}


     class ContainerTable {


   public int minX;  
   public int maxX;
   public int minY;
   public int maxY;
   private Color colorFilled;  
   private Color colorBorder;   

   public ContainerTable(int x, int y, int width, int height, Color colorFilled, Color colorBorder) {
          minX = x;
          minY = y;
          maxX = x + width - 1;
          maxY = y + height - 1;
          this.colorFilled = colorFilled;
          this.colorBorder = colorBorder;
       }

   public void set(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
          minX = x;
          minY = y;
          maxX = x + width - 1;
          maxY = y + height - 1;
       }


   public void draw(Graphics g) {
          g.setColor(colorFilled);
          g.fillRect(minX, minY, maxX - minX - 1, maxY - minY - 1);
          g.setColor(colorBorder);
          g.drawRect(minX, minY, maxX - minX - 1, maxY - minY - 1);

          Graphics2D southArc = ( Graphics2D ) g;
          southArc.setColor ( Color.WHITE );
          southArc.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
          southArc.drawArc ( 98, 640 , 300, 300 , 0, 180 );


          Graphics2D  northArc = ( Graphics2D ) g;
          northArc.setColor ( Color.WHITE );
          northArc.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
          northArc.drawArc ( 98, -143 , 300, 300 , 180, 180 );


          Graphics2D line = ( Graphics2D ) g;
          line.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
          line.setColor(Color.white);
          line.drawLine(4, 395, 491, 395);

          Graphics2D dot=(Graphics2D) g;
          dot.setColor(Color.black);

          for(int j=10;j<800;j+=20){
              for(int i=6;i<502;i+=20){

                  dot.drawLine(i, j, i, j);
              }
       }

       }

public int getMinX() {
    return minX;
}

public void setMinX(int minX) {
    this.minX = minX;
}

public int getMaxX() {
    return maxX;
}

public void setMaxX(int maxX) {
    this.maxX = maxX;
}

public int getMinY() {
    return minY;
}

public void setMinY(int minY) {
    this.minY = minY;
}

public int getMaxY() {
    return maxY;
}

public void setMaxY(int maxY) {
    this.maxY = maxY;
}}
```

Comment: Did you try logging or debugging in order to spot where the error is?

Comment: maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678624/collision-detection-for-circles could help?

Comment: As I said I don't have any idea for that ! I've tried nothing to debug. I hope to give some ideas here :)

Comment: Well, I don't see any code for your "Handle".  To hit the ball using handle, you will have to implement some of the newton's laws. Here is the gist to start you off  -- The x,y components of velocity of handle will be added to the ball, in ratio of their weights.

Comment: Danil , I couldn't solve it. :(

Comment: @PariaIghanian if you put your code on github (all of it), I'll clone it and see what I can do.  There are Swing classes missing?  Much easier to just clone your project than to copy-paste and try to fill in the missing classes.

Comment: Thufir, I edited it ;)

Comment: You may want to download:  http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/codes/ball_ex6a_circlemany.jar  which has source to work from.  Basically, the starting point for this, and please start over, is to make a Ball class.

Comment: ok, good :)     I wouldn't go overboard on the math, just go for basic functionality.  Keep asking questions, and be sure to cite your sources (this is for homework?).